# Mac bitcoin wallet stopped downloading the block chain

Tags: wallet, mac

The wallet is stuck on 95.48% as it has been for the last few days. Before this the blockchain downloaded fairly rapidly, I have updated the version of the wallet and restarted but this has not fixed the problem.

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: Voting to close this unanswered question about an unspecified piece of software. It's hard to imagine that anyone will ever find what we have so far to be of any use.